# Problems with z-index? Text not showing in front of elements with background-color

Tags: css, css-position, z-index

I'm trying to use CSS to make a simple "progress bar" type element.  For some reason, the text in the `.label` element is not showing in front of the bar, despite `z-index` being set. How can I make the text visible?

```css
#tech-entries {
  width: 200px;
padding: 5px;
}
.tech-entry {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}
.tech-entry .label {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 2px;
  z-index: 5;
  height: 15px;
}
.tech-entry .barbg,
.tech-entry .bar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 15px;
}
.tech-entry .barbg {
  background-color: white !important;
  width: 100%;
}
.tech-entry .bar {
  background-color: green !important;
  z-index: 4;
}
```

```html
<div id="tech-entries">
  <div class="tech-entry">
    <div class="label">test1</div>
    <div class="barbg"></div>
    <div class="bar" style="width: 99%;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tech-entry">
    <div class="label">test2</div>
    <div class="barbg"></div>
    <div class="bar" style="width: 65%;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tech-entry">
    <div class="label">test3</div>
    <div class="barbg"></div>
    <div class="bar" style="width: 88%;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`z-index` only applies top positioned elements, so you want to position your bar class absolutely and the label relatively.

```css
#tech-entries {
  width: 200px;
}

.tech-entry {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.tech-entry .label {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 2px;
  z-index: 5;
  height: 15px;
  color: white !important;
  position: relative;
}

.tech-entry .barbg,
.tech-entry .bar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 15px;
}

.tech-entry .barbg {
  background-color: gray !important;
  width: 100%;
}

.tech-entry .bar {
  background-color: green !important;
  z-index: 4;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="tech-entries">
  <div class="tech-entry">
    <div class="label">test1</div>
    <div class="barbg"></div>
    <div class="bar" style="width: 99%;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tech-entry">
    <div class="label">test2</div>
    <div class="barbg"></div>
    <div class="bar" style="width: 65%;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tech-entry">
    <div class="label">test3</div>
    <div class="barbg"></div>
    <div class="bar" style="width: 88%;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to  apply `position: absolute;` to that `.label`, other wise the `z-index` won't have any effect.

ADDITION AFTER COMMENT:

Apply the `height: 15px`, which you had for the label also to the parent element. The parent needs a defined height if all child elements are absolutely positioned, otherwise it would have 0 height since there is no static or relative content.

```css
#tech-entries {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: gray !important;
}

.tech-entry {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  height: 15px;
}

.tech-entry .label {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 2px;
  z-index: 5;
  color: white !important;
  height: 15px;
}

.tech-entry .barbg,
.tech-entry .bar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 15px;
}
.tech-entry .barbg {
  background-color: white !important;
  width: 100%;
}
.tech-entry .bar {
  background-color: green !important;
  z-index: 4;
}
```

```html
<div id="tech-entries">
  <div class="tech-entry">
    <div class="label">test1</div>
    <div class="barbg"></div>
    <div class="bar" style="width: 99%;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tech-entry">
    <div class="label">test2</div>
    <div class="barbg"></div>
    <div class="bar" style="width: 65%;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tech-entry">
    <div class="label">test3</div>
    <div class="barbg"></div>
    <div class="bar" style="width: 88%;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As you might expect, that completely breaks the layout. How can I fix it without creating a "placeholder' div or similar extraneous element?

Comment: @ScottBeeson what about `position: relative`?

Comment: see the addition/snippet to my answer

Answer (score 2):

Add `position:relative;` to `.label`

```css
#tech-entries {
  width: 200px;
}
.tech-entry {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}
.tech-entry .label {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 2px;
  z-index: 5;
  height: 15px;
  position:relative;
  color: white !important;
}
.tech-entry .barbg,
.tech-entry .bar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 15px;
}
.tech-entry .barbg {
  background-color: gray !important;
  width: 100%;
}
.tech-entry .bar {
  background-color: green !important;
  z-index: 4;
}
```

```html
<div id="tech-entries">
  <div class="tech-entry">
    <div class="label">test1</div>
    <div class="barbg"></div>
    <div class="bar" style="width: 99%;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tech-entry">
    <div class="label">test2</div>
    <div class="barbg"></div>
    <div class="bar" style="width: 65%;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tech-entry">
    <div class="label">test3</div>
    <div class="barbg"></div>
    <div class="bar" style="width: 88%;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `position: relative` to your `.label` class to get the effect of the z-index.

```css
#tech-entries {
  width: 200px;
}
.tech-entry {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}
.tech-entry .label {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 2px;
  z-index: 5;
  height: 15px;
  color: white !important;
  position: relative;
}
.tech-entry .barbg,
.tech-entry .bar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 15px;
}
.tech-entry .barbg {
  background-color: gray !important;
  width: 100%;
}
.tech-entry .bar {
  background-color: green !important;
  z-index: 4;
}
```

```html
<div id="tech-entries">
  <div class="tech-entry">
    <div class="label">test1</div>
    <div class="barbg"></div>
    <div class="bar" style="width: 99%;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tech-entry">
    <div class="label">test2</div>
    <div class="barbg"></div>
    <div class="bar" style="width: 65%;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tech-entry">
    <div class="label">test3</div>
    <div class="barbg"></div>
    <div class="bar" style="width: 88%;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```